# Electrical main disconnect problems

Tags: electrical, wiring, circuit-breaker

I will apologize now for my lack of grammar and terrible writing style I never learned in school so you will have to please bear with me I will try my best to explain it so maybe you can understand what the problem is

I bought a 1978 Mobile home about 10 years ago we have had issues with the power for as long as I have had the home but about 3 years ago the disconnect breaker outside at the meter started tripping randomly while nothing in the house tripped

After resetting it a few times it was fine but later that year the breaker started tripping again this time it had melted one side of the breaker all they way down to the harness that the breaker clips into

The wires seemed fine just the 100 amp breaker melted on the one side
They sent the maintenance crew out to replace the breaker and box and away the went

We started having power randomly go in and out on different parts of the house about 6 months later we could not determine the cause of the random blackouts of half the house and all 240v outlets furnace water heater dryer extra

then we lost one leg of the power totally I called the power company they said the problem was on our side I had to hunt on the internet to find out what was wrong because the power showed on but nothing 240 worked and appliances would not work on 120 but it showed 120 v I learned that I was back feeding from the water heater and as soon as I shut the 240 loads off the dead leg appeared

I was told by the maintenance crew and Thier so called electrician that the problem was inside the main breaker inside my home and that it was good at the disconnect to the house
But I had a dead leg incoming to my main breaker I was left for a month and a half with only my 120 v power working in the middle of winter in Ohio without a furnace

After checking every wire in the house and breaker box I decided to crawl underneath the home and there laying on the bare ground was a 50 amp receptacle box that my home plugged into that was incoming from the outside disconnect

I unplugged the cord coming from the box that served as a junction going into my main panel inside the home and found that half of the plug was completely burned up and destroyed how it had maintained intermittent power as long as it did with causing a fire is beyond me

Then I realized we had a backup in the sewer system and also some flooding early that year and the box must have been flooded and was exposed to the elements for as long as the home had been there

The maintenance crew came back out and just cut the cord and spliced it back together and left the mess still unprotected in a metal receptacle box

There are 3 wires coming from the meter disconnect under the house they tie into a four wire cord that is supposed to be 2 hots a neutral and a ground but there is no ground wire coming from the outside disconnect to underneath the house where this whole mess meets together

so this year  it happened again I lost that complete leg on the same side of the incoming wires into my main box before it goes into my main breaker

I checked the main outside disconnect it was not tripped but with my meter I was getting 240 v from the meter to the disconnect but on the outgoing side  of the disconnect I was showing 120 on each leg to neutral but 0 across both poles  and I had 120v inside my house on one side to neutral and 0 to neutral on the other side before it enters the main breaker

And I showed 120v across both hub's going into my inside main breaker inside the house so I called the manager back and he sent his flunkies back out and the still insist that the problem is in my box even I tell them I've lost a leg before it goes into my main breaker

I was perplexed for a while then I shut off all the 240v breakers and checked the disconnect again still 0 across the poles

Then I shut all the breakers and the main off in the house and checked the outside disconnect again this time it showed 240v across the poles

but I still only had 120 on one side of my main panel coming in from the disconnect I believe that it has burned out underneath where they just spliced it together on that same leg

but still does not explain why something in the main panel inside the house is blocking the main disconnect outside from showing 240 volts when the main breaker inside is on and showing full 240v when it's turned off I don't know if that is a secondary problem or part of the original problem

Also I believe I keep losing one leg because the wires from the disconnect to the house are 6 AWG made when the trailer park was built 60 years ago for trailers that were part gas for heating cooking and hot water than used 50 amp service

My mobile home is 100 amp Which after a little research I discovered it was originally supposed to be 200 amp service as it is all electric cooking water heating dryer and a 60 amp furnace alone plus a sun room that was added on but it has been 100 amp since I've owned it

I don't believe the 6 AWG wires are  heavy enough and that's why it keeps melting the main breaker outside but it's always on the same phase it doesn't seem to effect the other side

but I'm worried I have been damn lucky and it hasn't caught the house on fire so far
And I want them to properly fix the mess of wires underneath the house and explain why the ground wires go to nothing underneath there

and it's made to look like it has grounds inside as there is no ground at the meter disconnect and all the grounds and neutrals are mixed inside my main panel inside the house and bonded there

but the equipment ground it goes underneath and dies in that box that connects to nothing and there is no other grounding system on the property

But first off before I have them come check the wires underneath they messed up

what could cause something in the main panel inside the house to block the out side disconnect from showing 240 when the
House breaker is on

and the outside disconnect returns to normal 240v across when house main is off

or is that part of the same problem having to do with the missing leg but that shouldn't stop the outside disconnect from showing power

if it's dead underneath the house so what could be causing the interference between those main breakers

thanks for your time I hope I explained it enough for you all to mostly understand my issues funny thing is it would go long periods even years without issues and then randomly act up then finally fail

Comment: You their maintenance people out a few times and they kind of fix stuff.  Might be be time to get your own electrician or the local electrical inspector out to check things over.  This might fix the problem or might cause you to move out because of unsafe condition.

Comment: All I want to do is have it explained clearer to me so I can try to make them understand what's happening so we can work together to have a qualified electrician come out without calling out the calvery making my rental not worth it for him and his crew not catching my house on fire or getting me electrocuted

Comment: @JohnMinks are you able to take a few pics of the breaker/junction boxes and either [edit](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/249774/edit) your question to include them, or upload them to somewhere like [imgur](https://imgur.com/)?

Comment: For a rental you and the landlord have no choice but to have a licence electrician work on electrical problems.  Unless there is a licence electrician on the maintenance crew they cannot do the work.

Comment: Sorry the old 50 amp receptacle box is now just an empty box full of  the spliced wires they cut off and patched back together it connects the 3 incoming feeders to a 6 AWG four wire cord and the Fourth wire is just loose going nowhere there is not much left to see

Comment: He says the one man on the crew he sent out is supposed to be an electrician but all he has to say is it's my problem in.the breaker box in The house

Comment: The ground wires have nothing to do with an overloaded service, your trailer should have NEVER been connected (using #6 wires a 50 amp service ). There are no if’s ands or buts. I am amazed you have not had a fire or worse melted down the feeder. Only an open breaker fuse will prevent one leg from working but if you have a 100 amp panel and only a 50 amp feeder that is what the #6 is good for your wires should be closer to #2 coming from the 100 amp breaker to your panel. Normally the wire and connection from the outside main disconnect to your panel is your issue. Where are U located ? State?

Comment: I'm in Ohio what would cause the 240 outside disconnect to not have 240 across the breaker when the main breaker inside is in the on position but returns to normal 240v when main house breaker is off but still have the one dead leg coming into the house

Comment: Are you renting, or on a land contract?  Because you say "rent" but they say "it's all on you" and those contradict each other.  The only reason not to DIY this is that it's illegal for non-electricians to work on rental units. Maybe you say you're dumb to make people like you more, but you seem perfectly smart to me, you just need a keyboard with a working shift key and period and comma.

Comment: I rent the lot I own the home he's supposed to be responsible for where my cord connects to his wires underneath the trailer to the meter but they insist that the problem is with my main breaker inside the house but it's dead before it comes into my main breaker but something is different this time something is blocking the 240 v across the outside disconnect while the house main is on but turning off gets 240 v to show back at the disconnect but still leaves me with a dead leg inside

Comment: John, I used to live in Ohio and was not impressed with their electrical compliance to the code, back in the early 80’s I purchased a home that was wired with the neutral (white) as a hot not black. When you put a load on the feeder the power disappears is a sign of a failure turn everything off in the home on the good leg and leave only the bad leg on and measure the voltage there is nothing that can block the voltage but a open circuit in this case. You really need to upsize the feeder wire size from your panel to the outside disconnect if the voltage is gone in that case it is the park’s

Comment: Thank you Ed I will do that now and determine if there's a short in my panel thanks

Comment: I still show 16v to neutral on the dead leg with all breakers off except main how would I track down where the leg is broken